# Rails how to acess an param given in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an link to an site with an extraparam "icd1":

```
<%= link_to "#{s.von} - #{s.bis}  #{s.bezeichnung}", icd_show1_path(s, :icd1 => @icd1 )  %>
```

From this site i want to redirect, with the id given in @icd1:

```
<%= link_to "#{@icd2.von}  #{@icd2.bis} #{@icd2.bezeichnung}", icd_show_path(@icd1) %>
```

But i get the error:

```
Couldn't find Icd1 with id=icd1
{"id"=>"icd1"}
```

How can i access my param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [params object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).

So something like this:

```
@icd1 = params[:icd1]
```

That should let you access it in your view.